# Negative margins in email

Tags: html, email

Using python to send an email with HTML content.  The email is properly sent but the negative margins are not recognized.  Is there a way to convert this code so that it does not use negative margins and is still acceptable in most email readers?

```
<div style="width:40;">
   <img style="height:100px;" src="cid:{msg_image}" alt="LogoHeader" />
   <hr style="width:100%;margin-top:-30px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Um, remove the negative margins? :)

Comment: The `<hr>` must overlap the image by 30px.